# Delete file with # in Linux

Tags: linux

I want to delete a #tem.txt# called # that for some reason using emacs appeared

is between two # and I have not been able to remove it using rm, rm -f, unlink

[See my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4w3k.png)

Comment: *for some reason*? https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since '#' is a special character, you can try `rm \#tem.txt\#`

Comment: Thanks, you're right, you just had to escape the # with \

Comment: Glad it helps you, would you mind selecting me as the correct answer if it solved your problem?